# How to position a div scrollbar on the left hand side?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to specify a position (left or right hand side) for the placement of a vertical scrollbar on a div?

For example look at [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow)  which explains how to use the overflow attribute. Is there some way of placing that scrollbar on the left hand side of the scrollable area?

Comment: Have a look at this thread. Shows some of the limitations to this Im afraid. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123417/css3-how-do-i-position-a-left-scrollbar-on-a-tbody-element-of-a-table-for-google

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML element scrollbar on the left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772347/html-element-scrollbar-on-the-left)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```css
  .list_container {
    direction: rtl;
    overflow:auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }

  .item_direction {
    direction:ltr;
  }
```

```html
<div class="list_container">
  <div class="item_direction">1</div>
  <div class="item_direction">2</div>
  <div class="item_direction">3</div>
  <div class="item_direction">4</div>
  <div class="item_direction">5</div>
  <div class="item_direction">6</div>
  <div class="item_direction">7</div>
  <div class="item_direction">8</div>
  <div class="item_direction">9</div>
  <div class="item_direction">10</div>
  <div class="item_direction">11</div>
  <div class="item_direction">12</div>
</div>
```

#### Working Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jasonleonhard/tjwg02wu/)

or

### Cut and paste solution that works for all major browsers (Even Safari)

*Any height or width will work*

```
<style>
  .list_container {
    direction: rtl;
    overflow:auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }

  .item_direction {
    direction:ltr;
  }
</style>
<div class="list_container">
  <div class="item_direction">1</div>
  <div class="item_direction">2</div>
  <div class="item_direction">3</div>
  <div class="item_direction">4</div>
  <div class="item_direction">5</div>
  <div class="item_direction">6</div>
  <div class="item_direction">7</div>
  <div class="item_direction">8</div>
  <div class="item_direction">9</div>
  <div class="item_direction">10</div>
  <div class="item_direction">11</div>
  <div class="item_direction">12</div>
</div>
```

Optionally add `class="item_direction` to each item to change the direction of the text flow back, while preserving the container direction.

Comment: Happy to oblige.

Comment: As a side-note: This answer is not valid HTML as it has duplicate IDs.
It should be `class="item_direction"` instead of `id="item_direction"` and `.item_direction {` instead of `#item_direction {`.

Comment: Apologies, I responded quickly and made a mistake, you are correct and I have updated my answer.

Comment: You can also use another CSS rule to reset the direction on all direct children: `.list_container > * { direction: ltr; }`

Comment: What and absolute legend you are.

Answer (score 105):

You could try `direction:rtl;` in your css.  Then reset the text direction in the inner `div`

```
#scroll{
    direction:rtl; 
    overflow:auto; 
    height:50px; 
    width:50px;}

#scroll div{
    direction:ltr;
}
```

Untested.

Comment: I think IE and Opera are the only browsers to place the scrollbar on the left for RTL content.

Comment: @Joey not true also chrome under ubuntu

Comment: I want to confirm that Chrome 32 positions on the left. And at this point its not surprise that Firefox is a laggard in css

Comment: Chrome 39 windows also supports it.

Comment: Working on chrome/mac and firefox/mac but not safari/mac

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Mozilla left the scroll bar on the right for RTL content on purpose. At the time, we believed it would be a usability issue if the user would have to change his muscle-memory based on the current page content. I was taking part of that discussion, which can be found in Mozilla's Bugzilla.

Answer (score 54):

Kind of an old question, but I thought I should throw in a method which wasn't widely available when this question was asked.

You can reverse the side of the scrollbar in modern browsers using `transform: scaleX(-1)` on a parent `<div>`, then apply the same transform to reverse a child, "sleeve" element.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sleeve">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
  overflow: auto;
  transform: scaleX(-1); //Reflects the parent horizontally
}

.sleeve {
  transform: scaleX(-1); //Flips the child back to normal
}
```

Note: You may need to use an `-ms-transform` or `-webkit-transform` prefix for browsers as old as IE 9. Check [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) and click "show all" to see older browser requirements.

Comment: This is one of the most outstanding solutions.

Comment: Thanks! From what I understand, changing text direction works, too. The transform property just feels more... elegant? At least it's more semantically correct. :)

Comment: I think you also benefit from some GPU enhancements using this method. I'm flying in a menu from the right side of the screen and don't want the menu's scrollbar next to the page scrollbar ... too confusing.  I get less animation jank using this than the direction switching.

Comment: I Like that a L O O O T .. Thanks Man

Comment: This method can also be used to put the horizontal scrollbar on the top: `transform: scaleY(-1)`

Comment: `direction: rtl` doesn't change scrollbar position in Safari, but this method do.

Comment: Worth noting that transform establishes new coordinate system, for example for any fixed-positioned children elements, which is not intuitive. So proceed with caution. Old but sadly still relevant: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/09/12/un-fixing-fixed-elements-with-css-transforms/.

Comment: This is an incredible solution for me. The `direction: rtl` doesn't work on Safari. This one works well not only Safari but also Chrome and Firefox. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DomRamirez I love you for this

Comment: @Awjin I never thought I'd find love in such a way. I love you, too.

Answer (score 33):

I have the same problem. but when i add `direction: rtl;` in tabs and accordion combo but it crashes my structure.

The way to do it is add div with `direction: rtl;` as parent element, and for child div set `direction: ltr;`.

I use this first https://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```
$( ".your selector of child element" ).wrap( "<div class='scroll'></div>" );
```

then just simply work with css :)

In children div add to css

```
 .your_class {
            direction: ltr;    
        }
```

And to parent div added by jQuery with class .scroll

```
.scroll {
            unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
            direction: rtl;
            overflow: scroll;
            overflow-x: hidden!important;
        }
```

Works prefect for me

http://jsfiddle.net/jw3jsz08/1/

Comment: Or you could do css like this:

.scrollBarOnLeft {
 
    unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
    direction: rtl;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden!important;
}
.scrollBarOnLeft>div {
    direction: ltr;
}
.scrollBarOnLeft>div>div {
    
}

Answer (score 9):

No, you can't change scrollbars placement without any additional issues.

You can change text-direction to right-to-left ( rtl ), but it also change text position inside block.

This code can helps you, but I not sure it works in all browsers and OS.

```
<element style="direction: rtl; text-align: left;" />
```

Comment: I think IE and Opera are the only browsers to place the scrollbar on the left for RTL content.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done to make the right scroll bar work. The only thing needed to be considered is when using 'direction: rtl' and whole table also need to be changed. Hopefully this gives you an idea how to do it.

Example:

```
<table dir='rtl'><tr><td>Display Last</td><td>Display Second</td><td>Display First</td></table>
```

Check this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duez1pd1/)