# how to move scrollbar from left to right in css?

Tags: css

I have created a scrollbar in my webpage, this is in left of a division.
I dont know from where did I get to the position left.
How can I move it from left position to right position?

Comment: can you put some more information and examples of your code?

Comment: exactly what do you want to know?

Comment: A JsFiddle link containing your HTML and CSS that exactly replicates your situation.

Comment: `exactly what do you want to know?` this must be asked by us but not you. Describe everything related to your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to position a div scrollbar on the left hand side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347532/how-to-position-a-div-scrollbar-on-the-left-hand-side)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change direction from `rtl` to `ltr` in `#font6` style.

**For instance,**

```
#font6 {
    direction: ltr;
    display: block;
    height: 218px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 76px;
    top: 15px;
    width: 58%;
}
```

This will solve your issue.

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Solution could be right but where did the OP mention `#font6`?

Comment: I think that would not change the text direction, but only the scrollbar

Comment: He had pasted a link for the issue, which he later deleted. - @Mr_Green

Answer (score 4):

```css
html{
    overflow: hidden;
}
html, body {
 min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
 
}
body {
  
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    
}
```

```html
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl"><head>
 
</head>
<body> </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this css rule:

```
direction: rtl;
```

which moves the scrollbar in some browsers on the left

try to assign a div container with a scrollbar and one to the text contained in div containers set `direction: ltr;` to the div instead of the text set `direction: rtl;`