# How to change the Default scroll bar position in IE?

Tags: html, css

I have applied `direction:rtl;` on my html tag.Now the scrollbar is displayed at the left side of the window.Is there any way i can move this to right?

Comment: It is already answered. Check this link. Hope it helps,
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060845/how-to-move-scrollbar-from-left-to-right-in-css)

Comment: but this is for the scrollbar created by the user and he has an id for that..i am talking about the browser window scrollbar