# How to insert horizontal scroll bar at the top above listview

Tags: html, asp.net, listview, scrollbar

I am able to show a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the ListView, however I can figure out how to set it up at the top.

Here is my code:

```
<div style =" overflow :auto ;width:auto; height:auto">
//omitted
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" OnPagePropertiesChanged="ListView1_PagePropertiesChanged">
//omitted
</asp:ListView>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the browser will only display the scroll bars on the bottom and right side of the area that needs scrolling. In order to get the scroll bars on the top or the left, you'd have to create something that essentially mimics the opposite scroll bar.

There is a great explanation and example of how to do this here:
[horizontal scrollbar on top and bottom of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table)

There are also jQuery plugins as mentioned in the above post that do the same:
https://github.com/sniku/jQuery-doubleScroll

Comment: You can put vertical scrollbar to the left side using pure css direction:rtl wrapper, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347532/how-to-position-a-div-scrollbar-on-the-left-hand-side