# Show iframe scrollbar on left side in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have my piece of code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="parentDiv" style="border:1px solid blue;" dir="rtl">
   <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" height="500" width="700">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
   </iframe>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I run this code in Firefox or Chrome, I could not see the iframe scrollbar on the left side as it stays always on the right side of the iframe. But, in IE it works perfectly.

I would like to know if there is any CSS or JS solution for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347532/how-to-position-a-div-scrollbar-on-the-left-hand-side

Comment: @Rachel..my question was for iFrame and not a div within a div. I tried the css which is mentioned in the link which you given, unfortunately none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Et voila! a scrollable iframe with the scroll on the left

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/s3z17cLw/

```js
$( ".main" ).wrap( "<div class='scroll'></div>" );
```

```css
div.main {
     height:150px!important;
     float:left;
     direction: ltr;
    
}
.scroll {
      unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
      direction: rtl;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      overflow-x:hidden;
}
.inside{
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main" ><iframe class="inside" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3309.3312622412445!2d-83.37737678492407!3d33.958324180631536!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88f66cdecc8d0783%3A0x4f152e9d93fa5d6!2s170+College+Ave%2C+Athens%2C+GA+30601%2C+USA!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sie!4v1464026910465" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we cannot show the Iframe scrollbar on the left side in chrome when the html dir tag holds the "rtl" value. I just found the answer in this [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17nb3wlYkIG9MNtL1mlXVPOVe4QwyApiHRYim3nTi5CE/edit?hl=en_US&ndplr=1#.).

For Firefox, it is same as chrome browser and the answer lies in this [link](https://www.w3.org/International/tests/repo/results/native-user-interfaces#alertbox).