# How to force browser to show scrollbar at the left side of browser using CSS or Javascript?

Tags: html, css

I am developing a multilingual website so I need to show browser's scrollbar at the left side of window. Is there are any way that I can change the position of scrollbar using CSS or Javascript??

Comment: What have you tried here?

Comment: Related or not, why would you need to reposition the scrollbar? Shouldn't the user expect browser behavior like scrollbar-positioning to be standardized across all websites according to their environment/localization?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347532/how-to-position-a-div-scrollbar-on-the-left-hand-side)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to position a div scrollbar on the left hand side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347532/how-to-position-a-div-scrollbar-on-the-left-hand-side)

Answer (score 2):

You can force things a bit, many are probably going to see this as "non-standard" but that is not the question really.  Let's force the things.  Normally you would set `overflow: auto;` on this but I force a scroll just to show it here.  To be fair, I have ONLY tested this on the single chrome version I am using.

```css
body {
  direction: rtl;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}

.bodycontainer {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bodycontainer">
    Here I am, I need more text just to force me to scroll the scroll on the scroll of the body with my super bad width and height things I set on the body
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: NOTE: I have no idea how this will behave with mobile or things like tables or other HTML elements, may take a good bit of customization for each or other solutions like some fancy markup or script, I leave that to the user to add lots of other questions :)