# How to move vertical scroll bar to the right?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, scroll

I am using `React-Perfect-Scrollbar` to add a custom scroll bar. Default position is left of the containing div. I need to move it to the right of the div. how to do that?

Current look of the code

```
import 'react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css';
import PerfectScrollbar from 'react-perfect-scrollbar'

...
<div className="tabcontent-2">
  <PerfectScrollbar>
    <p>{this.state.currentProject.description}</p>
  </PerfectScrollbar>
</div>
...
```

Current look of the UI

[image]

I couldn't find a `option` given by the `module` to do that. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you check https://mdbootstrap.com/freebies/perfect-scrollbar/#beforeusingperfectscrollbar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989872/how-to-force-browser-to-show-scrollbar-at-the-left-side-of-browser-using-css-or

Comment: I think it's pretty much always a bad idea to make a custom scrollbar, it's something the device knows how to handle best imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this Document

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/javascript/scroll/#smooth-scroll

You can set the scrollY position in the `onScroll`

```
var myCustomScrollbar = document.querySelector('.my-custom-scrollbar');
var ps = new PerfectScrollbar(myCustomScrollbar);

var scrollbarY = myCustomScrollbar.querySelector('.ps.ps--active-y>.ps__scrollbar-y-rail');

myCustomScrollbar.onscroll = function() {
  scrollbarY.style.cssText = `top: ${this.scrollTop}px!important; height: 400px; right: ${-this.scrollLeft}px`;
}
```

In the React. I think you can update with scrollbar ref

```
class Container extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollBar
        ref = {(ref) => { this._scrollBarRef = ref; }}
      >
        ...
       <ChildComponent
        onUpdateSize = {() => { this._scrollBarRef.updateScroll(); }}
       />
        ...
      </ScrollBar>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found useful answer, and playing with 'options' param didn't help too, so I made it using global styles:

```
.ps__rail-y {
  left: unset;
  right: 0;
}
```