# CSS Grid Layout - How to put scrollbar on left, and populate left to right

Tags: html, css, angularjs, css-grid, grid-layout

### How to put scrollbar on left, but have ng-repeat populate left to right

I am using an ng-repeat to fill a grid that is 3 by X (Width by height), by default the scroll bar is on the right, per normal webview standards, I want to place it on the left, so I used [`direction: rtl;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction) The problem with this however is now my `ng-repeat` data also fills in right to left, but i need that data to appear left to right, like it normally would.

From my understanding `direction:rtl` is the only way to move a scrollbar to the otherside, is there some tool that I am missing that can move the scrollbar that isn't `direction: rtl`, or is there another method to flip my content back to ltr?

My HTML:

```
<div class="h-blue-holding-grid">
  <div class="blue-holding-item" ng-repeat='img in recipeArray'>
    <div class="h-blue-holdingImg"><img src="/imgs/redhead.png" width="45" height="45"></img></div>
    <div class="h-blue-smalltime">{{Math.floor(img.data.data.start_time_ms/1000/60)}}:{{img.data.data.start_time_ms/1000%60}}<span ng-if="img.data.data.start_time_ms/1000%60 < 10">0</span></div>
    <div class="h-blue-smallfont">{{img.data.data.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.h-blue-holding-grid{
  width: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
  grid-gap: 3px 3px;
  margin-right: 5vh;
  height: 25.5vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  direction: rtl;
}
.blue-holding-item{
  width: 100%;
  height: 8vh;
  text-align: left;
  background-image: url(/imgs/gradient_blue.png);
  background-size: 20vh 8vh;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  font-weight: bold;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
.h-blue-holdingImg{
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3
}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding direction:ltr to the child elements, for you it should work like this:

```
.blue-holding-item {
    direction:ltr;
}
```

Is this what you want?

**===== Update =====**

First, it is not a problem with ng-repeat, it is just plain css and it works as expected. If you have access to the html you need an extra div as the wrapper of the .blue-holding-item, to it you will assign the direction:ltr; and everything will work.

Working example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wVeyQg

Comment: no, the grid still populates right to left, putting ltr on the child element just ensures the image stays on the lft of the child and the text on the right

Answer (score 0):

> is there some [method] that can move the scrollbar that isn't `direction: rtl`?

You can reverse the side of the scrollbar in modern browsers using `transform: scaleX(-1)` on a parent `<div>`, then apply the same transform to reverse a child, "sleeve" element.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sleeve">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
  overflow: auto;
  transform: scaleX(-1); //Reflects the parent horizontally
}

.sleeve {
  transform: scaleX(-1); //Flips the child back to normal
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45824265/5535245) in [How to position a div scrollbar on the left hand side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347532/how-to-position-a-div-scrollbar-on-the-left-hand-side)

Comment: this does not solve my issue as my grid now fills right to left which i do not want it to do. My goal is to have scroll bar one left, but my grid still be populated left to right as well