# Can I move the body scrollbar to the left of a specific HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, scrollbar

I am adding a sidebar to the right of the body, giving the body a margin-right of 50px and placing the sidebar in this margin. Currently on scroll, the body scrollbar will show up on top of the sidebar, but I'd like to place the scroll bar to the left hand side of the sidebar. How could I do this? I do not want to create my own constantly present scrollbar (what working with ::webkit-scrollbar is doing), I just want to move the body scrollbar left 50px and the functionality where it will only show onScroll to continue. `body { margin-right: 50px } .sidebar { position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 50px; }`

Comment: Could you please paste your piece of code ?

Comment: This might help <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347532/how-to-position-a-div-scrollbar-on-the-left-hand-side>

Comment: Do you mean you want to scroll your body only?