# How to change the vertical scrollbar position but keep the horizontal scrollbar scrollpostion (css only)

Tags: html, css

Firstly the definitions:

**Scroll position** is the current position of the scroll-handle on the scrollbar.

**Position of the scrollbar** is the side of the element(div) the scrollbar is positioned on (default for ltr is left)

I want to have the vertical scrollbar positioned on the right side of a div (representation of a tree), while still having the content ltr. I quickly found at least two [ways to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347532/how-to-position-a-div-scrollbar-on-the-left-hand-side).
Now I have still a problem when applying any of the solution that the horizontal scrollbar position is initially set to the right. As my content is still ltr the scroll-position is at the end of the content, which is not at all what I wanted to achieve. Furthermore Users would have to "scroll back" to the all of the content, which is rather bad UX).

There is the possibility to set the scroll position with Javascript but sadly I can not use Javascript in this case.

```css
.main {
     width:150px;
     height:150px;
     direction: rtl;
     overflow:scroll;
}
.inside {
      direction: ltr;
      width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"><div class="inside">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquam lectus vel erat feugiat, id maximus quam iaculis. Etiam vitae eleifend nisi. Phasellus pellentesque dui ex. Proin sit amet metus quis quam sagittis pretium at ac velit. Mauris ultricies metus nec tortor dignissim, in pellentesque libero consectetur. Nullam nec enim sit amet leo congue finibus. Curabitur ligula dolor, aliquet eget erat et, laoreet vehicula nibh. Suspendisse eu lacus sapien. Nulla facilisi. Nulla placerat mauris sit amet ultrices sollicitudin. Quisque sed bibendum ante. Integer id magna sollicitudin, scelerisque neque vitae, tincidunt quam. Integer et aliquam sem, at tempus dui. Etiam sit amet ornare lacus, at placerat leo. Donec pharetra diam sit amet nisl dapibus suscipit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. SedNulla placerat mauris sit amet ultrices sollicitudin. Quisque sed bibendum ante. Integer id magna sollicitudin, scelerisque neque vitae, tincidunt quam. Integer et aliquam sem, at tempus dui. Etiam sit amet ornare lacus, at placerat leo. Donec pharetra diam sit amet nisl dapibus suscipit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed</div></div>
```

Here is an [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uc3asvnm/)

Tested on Firefox:
[image: FF_screenshot_of_fiddle]

Update:

I did achieve the effect I wanted in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o75h206t/) but it does only work with fixed pixel values, which is not an option.

Comment: Does it work when you change the `.main` direction to `ltr`?

Comment: yes it does work, but then the vertical scrollbar is back on the right and it must be on the left.

Comment: Okay, i was just wondering because it looks like this for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/te4qA.png when i refresh it and change it to `ltr`

Comment: That's strange, what browser are you on? The normal behaviour should be that the v-scrollbar is back on the right.

Comment: maybe it's because of cache of your browser, press ctrl + f5 it's gonna load the latest changes on files.

Comment: Yes, that's why i didn't understand your comment i'm sorry it was my fault. I use the latest version of firefox

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer today.
It is to use `flex-direction: row-reverse` and `min-width`.
So now I can delete the JS workaround hack which did never worked fully.

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    direction: rtl;
    overflow: auto;
}
.inside {
    direction: ltr;
    display: block;
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mj5rqb24/)